# Disable form button if required field has no value

Tags: angular, abp

I'm working on the Abp framework with Angular UI. Right now, I'm working with Account personal settings, and I override some columns to be required so I created a contributor like this:

```
import {
  AccountEditFormPropContributors,
  eAccountComponents
} from '@abp/ng.account';
import { UpdateProfileDto } from '@abp/ng.account.core/proxy';

import {
  FormProp,
  FormPropList,
  ePropType
} from '@abp/ng.theme.shared/extensions';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { TimeZoneService } from '@proxy/dci/aggregator/time-zones';
import { map } from 'rxjs';
interface Option<T> {
  key: string;
  value: T | undefined;
}

export function validatePersonalSettingsContributors(
  propList: FormPropList<UpdateProfileDto>
) {
  //drop current properties
  propList.dropByValue(
    'AbpIdentity::DisplayName:Name',
    (prop, displayName) => prop.displayName === displayName
  );

  propList.dropByValue(
    'AbpIdentity::DisplayName:Surname',
    (prop, displayName) => prop.displayName === displayName
  );

  propList.dropByValue(
    '::TimeZone',
    (prop, displayName) => prop.displayName === displayName
  );

  const firstNameProp = new FormProp<UpdateProfileDto>({
    type: ePropType.String,
    name: 'name',
    displayName: 'AbpIdentity::FirstName',
    validators: () => [Validators.required]
  });
  propList.addByIndex(firstNameProp, 1);

  const lastNameProp = new FormProp<UpdateProfileDto>({
    type: ePropType.String,
    name: 'surname',
    displayName: 'AbpIdentity::LastName',
    validators: () => [Validators.required]
  });

  propList.addByIndex(lastNameProp, 2);

  const timeZoneProp = new FormProp<UpdateProfileDto>({
    type: ePropType.Typeahead,
    name: 'TimeZoneId',
    displayName: '::TimeZone',
    isExtra: true,
    id: 'TimeZoneId',
    autocomplete: 'off',
    validators: () => [Validators.required],
    options: data => {
      const service = data.getInjected(TimeZoneService);
      return service
        .getList()
        .pipe(
          map(
            response =>
              response.items?.map(
                item =>
                  ({ key: item.description, value: item.id } as Option<any>)
              ) || []
          )
        );
    }
  });

  propList.addByIndex(timeZoneProp, 5);
}

export const accountEditFormPropContributors: AccountEditFormPropContributors =
  {
    [eAccountComponents.PersonalSettings]: [
      validatePersonalSettingsContributors
    ]
  };

export const identityEditFormPropContributors = accountEditFormPropContributors;
```

As you can see, I added some required fields to my form; if you try to submit the form with no input in a required field it will throw a validation:

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the Save button is enabled; in other framework forms like user creation, if a required field has any value, the save button gets Disabled. I have no idea why this is not the case. How can I add that functionality to my Account Personal Settings form?

Comment: and you didn set `[disabled]` on a button right?

Comment: *if a required field has any value, the save button gets Disabled* - false, if **required** field has **any value**, therfore it is valid and can be submited

Comment: Abp autogenerates that form, so we cannot access the HTML or .TS class. @Antoniossss